# OrderBy virtual property in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to `orderby` virtual properties on an entity?

I have a class similar to:

```
public int Id{get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}

public virtual string TestName
{
   get { return string.Format("{0}{1}", Name , Id); }
}
```

When i order by the TestName property, i get the error:

> "The specified type member 'TestName' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported."

I originally had the method in a partial class, the property is used in returning data but not ordering.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I suspect you have to specify read-only or non mapped.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the property being `virtual`. You get the error because the collection you call `OrderBy` on is an `IQueryable<T>` therefore EF tries to create **SQL** out of it. Since the DB does not know that property, it cannot order by it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just `.OrderBy(x => x.TestName)` you must instead use `.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.TestName)` on your EF query.

This is because the `TestName` property does not exist as a column in the database table and the query cannot be converted to a SQL statement. The `.ToList()` call will materialize the query into a C# collection which can then be ordered.

Comment: This would work, but i'm trying to do a search query on a large collection of this class and ToList() would performance implications

Answer (score 1):

You can use DelegateDecompiler to expand the code inside a property to an expression tree, which means Linq to Entities can generate SQL from it.

https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler

You simply need to decorate the property with the `[Computed]` attribute, and call `.Decompile()` as part of the linq query.